# Cypress - how to get a dynamic value in table

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm trying to get the dynamic value from a table that is currently '62' right now but will change. I tried:

```js
 cy.get('tbody>tr').eq(0)
   .find("td").eq(1)
   .then(text => {
    const rowText = text;
    cy.log(rowText)
```

But it's outputing

```html
<td.MuiTableCell-root.MuiTableCell-body.MuiTableCell-alignCenter.MuiTableCell-sizeMedium.css-1cjito2>
```

instead of 62

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable yielded by your `.find('td').eq(1)` is not a text variable, but a JQuery Element. You'll need to abstract that value. You can do that by `cy.invoke()`, or using the JQuery `.text()` function.

```js
cy.get('tbody>tr').eq(0)
   .find("td").eq(1)
   .invoke('text')
   .then(text => {
     cy.log(text);
   });

cy.get('tbody>tr').eq(0)
   .find("td").eq(1)
   .then($el => {
     cy.log($el.text());
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for that explaination and that worked!

Answer (score 3):

For **dynamic text** (changing after a time), you would need to apply a retry using a `.should()` statement.

The accepted answer does not do that, so probably will be flaky.

This is a more solid test.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').eq(0)
  .find('td').eq(1)
  .should('have.text', newText)   // assert text after change, retries until true
  .then($cell => {
    cy.log('Cell @0,1 text:', $cell.text())
  })
```

Or with `invoke()`

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').eq(0)
  .find('td').eq(1)
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', newText)   // assert text after change, retries until true
  .then(cellText => {
    cy.log('Cell @0,1 text:', cellText)
  })
```